# Change URL when visiting wordpress site

Tags: wp-config, domain, configuration, dns

I have a wordpress site being hosted by an Apache server and I have a domain name set up to forward to the ip address of that server. However whenever I use the domain name to visit the site, the domain name changes into the ip address.

I've tried looking for solutions online but every result says to change the site address. I have done this and it still is having issues.

Answer (score 1):

What configuration have you got in your Settings > General? Make sure your Wordpress Address and Site Address refer to your url and not the IP Address.

Comment: I have the wordpress address as the ip address and the site address as my domain name. Should I change the wordpress address as well? I did that in the past but then I wasn't able to access my site anymore.

Comment: Provided you have database access it is not a problem as you can easily change it back. I recently cloned a site and every time I visited I got the old address, it wasn’t until I changed the WordPress and Site Addresses that I was able to access the new setup. According to WP Support the Site Address is the url you need to use to access your site, and he WordPress Address is where your Wordpress install is (https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/). You may also need to check the settings for your domain on your host.